# How to make the object follow another object's vertex

Tags: animation, objects, vertices

How to make the object follow another object's vertex?

Comment: related to http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/34324/how-do-i-stick-an-object-to-another-objects-vertex?rq=1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Select the 'Follower', then the Object containing the vertex to follow. <kbd>Tab</kbd> into *Edit Mode* then press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd>, a popup menu for 'Parenting' should come up (*Set Parent To*) with the options *Object* or *Vertex*. See the [Manual](https://www.blender.org/manual/modeling/objects/parents.html#vertex-parent-from-edit-mode) for further details.