# How to have 2 or more dynamic paints on a single object?

Tags: dynamic-paint

I have a Waved Object (Blue surface) that need to Wet the Red Cubes fall into it, how to make that happen? Only one Dynamic paint can be applied to surface at a time,

Is it possible to cache, or convert-to-frame the Waved Deformation, and then apply a new Brush Dynamic Paint to surface?

Any other workarounds would appreciated!

[image]

Comment: How made you this drop in the water (bounce) & swim effect?

Comment: If you interested, I'd like to manually animate the cubes as brushes and the surface is a refined cube dynamic-paint canvas that builds wave.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it's not possible for an object to be a brush and a canvas at the same time.

You can bake the Dynamic Paint as an *Image Sequence*. But I am not sure if this helps in this case and I don't know if you can use the baked cache data of the waves.

**A working solution is to fake the effect with a duplicated setup**:

[image: cube falls into water animation]

It's basically what you have already:

- a **cube** that works as a **brush** to create the **waves**
- a **pool/liquid** (cube) that is the **canvas** to get the **waves**

plus additionally,

- **another cube** that acts as **canvas** to get the **wet effect**. It's overlayed to the brush cube and slightly **scaled-up** so the brush cube is inside of it and cannot paint on it. The canvas cube is parented to the brush via *Parent Type* = *3 Vertices* to follow the soft body physics. This can also be used to create a [swim effect](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/34324/how-do-i-stick-an-object-to-another-objects-vertex) (not used here).
- a **flat cuboid** that is right under the surface of the pool that is a **brush** and paints on the canvas cube to make it wet. For more realism, you can use a *Mesh Deform* modifier and bind it to the pool mesh so it gets also wave deformations. The *Dynamic Paint* modifier must be the last one on the stack (bottom).

[image: screenshot 1]

The **canvas** objects need some **subdivisions** to have vertices that can be colorized.

Use the *Vertex Color* node in the *Shader Editor* to make the vertex color visible in the material preview and final render.

Comment: Thanks Blunder, for this descriptive answer, I really appreciate it and also tagged it as current Correct answer!

Comment: Also the "Mesh Deform" Modifier doesn't work in this case, I used "Surface Deform"! Thanks again